# Android app that shows WiFi password

Tags: android, open-source, wifi

I need to share WiFi password with my notebook, because it has better antennae. Is there an open source Android app that allows see the WiFi pass of existing connection?

Comment: Only on rooted devices. Are such answers acceptable? If so, take a look at my app listing on [WiFi Password Recovery](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_wifi_config#group_423). Though the only one I see that definitely is open source requires Xposed and wasn't updated for a while…

Comment: If answer explains why no such app exists for non-rooted devices - this is a good answer. And if adb can still fetch the info - it is good to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Android devices, WiFi passwords are stored in an area no "normal" app can access (if you are interested in details, it's [file system permissions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions#Traditional_Unix_permissions) behind this). Thus, if an app shall access stored WiFi passwords, it requires root access. Without root powers – no way, to my knowledge not even via ADB¹.

If you take a look at my app listings on [WiFi Password Recovery](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_wifi_config#group_423) you will see that all those apps require root access. And if you have root access, you don't need an app for that – you can simply access the `/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf` file directly and see the password (`psk`) for each network (`ssid`) you connected, plain text.

That said, I don't know of any up-to-date open-source app for this.

---

¹ <sub>only place that could work would be examining a full ADB backup, but I doubt it's in there</sub>